# Python/Fabric: set count to increment

Tags: python, fabric

I am trying to increment IP addresses by providing a starting 4th octet.

Usage:

```
fab set_ip:ip="5" set_hosts:file="./ip-list" subnet_2016:gateway="10.0.7.99"
```

This is my latest shot at this:

```
def set_ip(start_ip):
        global start_ip
        start_ip = int(start_ip)

def subnet_2016(gateway):
        oct = re.match('^\d+\.\d+\.\d+', gateway).group(0)
        print(gateway)
        global start_ip
        search_replace_ip(gateway, oct, start_ip)    
        start_ip = start_ip + 1 
#       reboot()

def search_replace_ip(gateway, oct, count):    
        print("subnet is %s " % (oct))
        run("sed -re \'/address/s/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/%s\.%s/\' -e \'/gateway/s/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/%s/\' %s" % (oct, count, gateway, env.network_conf))
```

When I run it it complains about:

> SyntaxError: name 'start_ip' is local and global

However -- other iterations I've tried don't increment the IP. What simple concept have I missed?

**EDIT - UPDATE**
This works -- would you write this differently, as far as the incrementation part?

```
start_ip = 0
def set_ip(ip):
        global start_ip
        start_ip = int(ip)

def subnet_2016(gateway):
        oct = re.match('^\d+\.\d+\.\d+', gateway).group(0)
        print(gateway)
        global start_ip
        search_replace_ip(gateway, oct, start_ip)    
        start_ip = start_ip + 1
```

Comment: The simple concept you have missed is passing arguments to functions. Why are you both trying to pass `start_ip` as an argument (`def set_ip(start_ip)`) and then access it under the same name as a global (`global start_ip`). What you're doing with global is wrong and most likely does not need to be done.

Comment: Note that Python will search upwards in scope from your functions to the top of the file. If you have something in module scope (defined all the way to the left in the file), your functions can find it automatically as long as they don't overwrite the name.

Comment: Please see my update. It works but is the `set_ip` part unnecessary?

Comment: On one hand, classically speaking global scope can be a mess and there are numerous other ways to do what you're doing without using it. On the other hand, you've got something that works. It's hard to really evaluate without knowing a lot more about your project. I can tell you it's at least not much of a function. All it does is try an `int` conversion and it doesn't even really handle the error. Minus the global scope, you could almost say `set_ip = int` and get the same result.

Comment: The only criteria I have for this project is that IT staff need to be able to specify a starting ip [ 4th octet only ]. If there is a location with 10 hosts, it will start at, say 5, and use the gateway to set IPs in order. This does just that -- but there may be a simpler way to achieve this I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario:
There is a location with 10 Linux hosts that need to be put on a different subnet. Old subnet: 10.10.16.0/24, New subnet: 10.0.7.0/24. You also want to clean up the IP addresses by having them start in a particular range to avoid creeping into the DHCP range you've allotted. Enter Fabric:

The following satisfies the parameters of:

- Provide starting IP counter
- Provide gateway to base subnet on as well as set gateway for Linux hosts
- Writes changes to `/etc/network/interfaces` file
- Reboot stations

Usage example:
`fab set_ip:ip="5" set_hosts:file="./ip-list" subnet_2016:gateway="10.0.7.99"`

```
start_ip = 0
def set_ip(ip):
        global start_ip
        start_ip = int(ip)

def subnet_2016(gateway):
        oct = re.match('^\d+\.\d+\.\d+', gateway).group(0)
        print(gateway)
        global start_ip
        search_replace_ip(gateway, oct, start_ip)    
        start_ip = start_ip + 1 
#       reboot()

def search_replace_ip(gateway, oct, count):    
        print("subnet is %s " % (oct))
        run("sed -i -re \'/address/s/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/%s\.%s/\' -e \'/gateway/s/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/%s/\' %s" % (oct, count, gateway, env.network_conf))
```

Requires a file with IP addresses of hosts.